# converting bytecode structures to and from XML using ASM

Tags: xml, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have been using `ASM` to do several stuff like parsing java classes using `ClassVisitor` method provided by `ASM`. As I know it provides other packages too , I want to understand `XML` package functionality to convert `bytecode` structures to and from `XML`. Can you please provide me the java example how we can achieve that?

Thanks a lot .

~yash

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you really using assembly to parse java classes? Assembly does not have a `ClassVisitor` nor an XML package.

Comment: @PMF: I think he's referring to [this ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) (some sort of Java bytecode framework).

Comment: Hi ,thaks for the response, I have already used ASM to parse .class and its works. What I have asked is not related to parsing , I want to unserstand ASM feature provided by XML package as mentioned here - http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/index.html , can you please explaing how it works? Thankyou :)

Comment: @Michael: Ok, I thought something along that line. I've removed the "assembly" tag, as it is misleading.

Comment: I'm still confused by the question. Normally you use an XML parser/serializer package to read and write XML. I hope you aren't talking about reinventing that wheel...

Answer (score 2):

There are [some JavaDoc](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/xml/package-summary.html) at the package level of `asm-xml` package. Basically it provides a bi-directional bridge between ASM's visitor events and XML SAX events. That allows to convert stream of those events to and from XML, as well as hook up XML processing tools, such as XSLT into that. You can find a few examples of XSLTs in the examples/xml folder in the ASM distribution package or in [SVN](http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=asm&path=/trunk/asm/examples/xml/).

For example, you can add the equivalent of following Java code for each label in the bytecode that has source line number information:

```
System.err.println( "<class>.<method><desc> Line:<source line number>");
```

Using this XSL transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ASCII" />

<xsl:template match="//method/code/Label">
  <xsl:variable name="n"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="c"><xsl:value-of select="../LineNumber[@start=$n]/@line"/></xsl:variable>

  <label><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/></label>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($c)>0">
    <xsl:comment>
      <xsl:text> Line: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$c"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:comment>

    <GETSTATIC desc="Ljava/io/PrintStream;" name="err" owner="java/lang/System"/>
    <LDC desc="Ljava/lang/String;">
      <xsl:attribute name="cst">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat( /class/@name, '.' ,../../@name, ../../@desc, ' Line:', $c)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </LDC>
    <INVOKEVIRTUAL desc="(Ljava/lang/String;)V" name="println" owner="java/io/PrintStream"/>
  </xsl:if>    

</xsl:template>

<!-- copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You should be able to run it using the following command:

```
java -jar asm-all.jar code code -in <input jar> -out <output jar> -xslt <xsl>
```

Also look at the [JavaDoc](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/xml/Processor.html) and [source code](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=/trunk/asm/src/org/objectweb/asm/xml/Processor.java) of `org.objectweb.asm.xml.Processor` class.